# randomly remove rows based on condition for one column in r

Tags: r, dplyr

I need to balance my training set for a machine learning task where two categories are unevenly represented in a df. I need an equal number of rows, so I need to remove at random rows from the larger category:

```
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(123)

mydata <- 
  tibble(
    prod = sample(c("durum", "bread"), size = 1000, replace = T),
    value = sample(0:20, size = 1000, replace = T)
  )

prod_rows <- mydata %>% count(prod)
prod_rows

# A tibble: 2 x 2
  prod      n
* <chr> <int>
1 bread   494
2 durum   506
```

So I tried

```
mydata_new <- mydata[- sample(1:nrow(mydata), abs(prod_rows$n[1] - prod_rows$n[2])), ]
```

Which works, but I want to remove only from rows where `mydata$prod == "durum"`. That is, only from the larger category

The answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64115280/how-to-randomly-remove-rows-in-dataframe-but-for-a-specific-subgroup-only-with) does most of what I would like to achieve. However I need to retain the order of the rows as per original df, so can't separate then use `bind_rows()` to replace them.

Comment: What do you mean by `I need to retain the order of the rows as per original df`. Do you want to remove 12 row where `prod == "durum"` from the last?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a new column to maintain the original order of rows.

```
library(dplyr)

keep_df <- prod_rows %>%
  summarise(prod = prod[which.max(n)], 
            n = min(n))
keep_df

# A tibble: 1 x 2
#  prod      n
#  <chr> <int>
#1 durum   494

mydata <- mydata %>% mutate(original_order = row_number())
  
# A tibble: 1,000 x 3
#   prod  value original_order
#   <chr> <int>          <int>
# 1 durum    12              1
# 2 durum     7              2
# 3 durum     1              3
# 4 bread     5              4
# 5 durum    16              5
# 6 bread    13              6
# 7 bread     6              7
# 8 bread    12              8
# 9 durum     7              9
#10 durum     5             10
# … with 990 more rows
```

Remove the additional row and bind the data and `arrange` the data according to original order.

```
mydata %>%
  inner_join(keep_df, by = 'prod') %>%
  sample_n(first(n)) %>%
  bind_rows(mydata %>% anti_join(keep_df, by = 'prod')) %>%
  arrange(original_order) %>% 
  select(-original_order, -n) -> result

result

# A tibble: 988 x 2
#   prod  value
#   <chr> <int>
# 1 durum    12
# 2 durum     7
# 3 durum     1
# 4 bread     5
# 5 bread    13
# 6 bread     6
# 7 bread    12
# 8 durum     7
# 9 durum     5
#10 bread    10
# … with 978 more rows
```

Check `result` :

```
result %>% count(prod)

# A tibble: 2 x 2
#  prod      n
#  <chr> <int>
#1 bread   494
#2 durum   494
```

Comment: Could you please point out where the random selection of rows to remove happens, if it does? This is an important aspect. It seems possible to use `slice_sample(n = length(mydata$prod) - length(mydata$prod[mydata$prod == remove_df$prod]))` but not sure this is the simplest way.

Comment: The answer was not removing random selection of rows. It was removing extra rows from the bottom. I have updated the answer now to remove rows using random selection.